# Rules files in apache ant

Tags: java, ant, build

I have 4 apache ant build files that all use findbugs,junit,and jacoco. At this time the only way I know to include the tools in the ant build file is to define them each time which I find not very efficient as what I am working on grows. Is there a way to define a file that holds the rules for junit,jacoco, and find bugs that the ant build files can just load kind of like a rules file in make, or am I stuck have to define the same task in each ant file fully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a single Ant buildfile in which you centralize *all* external (third-party) task definitions.

Whenever an Ant buildfile needs to use these tasks, you can [import](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html) this buildfile:

```
<project name="MyProject" ...>
   <import file="${path_to_file}/tasks_ext.xml"/>
   ...
</project>
```

Comment: Gotcha so if the directory structure has a root that holds the source file folders I can define a build.xml in the root with all the task and import that file into each ant build.xml file in the different source directory's?

Comment: If each build.xml is independent from the other (i.e. they don't have a single entry point), then yes you would have to import that root build.xml in each of them.